# PHP soap is not working with new version

Tags: php, soap, php-7

Old version:

> PHP Version 5.3

New version:

> PHP Version 7.0.4

in this code:

```
$this->wsdl = & new wsdl('', $this->proxyhost, $this->proxyport, $this->proxyusername, $this->proxypassword, $this->timeout, $this->response_timeout, $this->curl_options, $this->use_curl);
```

Now, when I host the same PHP web application in new version I face the error following:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'new' (T_NEW) in 
    D:\xampp\htdocs\website\libs\nusoap.php on line 7385
```

As far as I know it's because of the change on PHP version.

please share your experience.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Please share the code that is causing the problem.

Comment: @AmrElAdawy did

Comment: https://php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.other

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `&` so your code should be like:

```
$this->wsdl =  new wsdl('', $this->proxyhost, $this->proxyport,
                          $this->proxyusername, $this->proxypassword,
                           $this->timeout, $this->response_timeout, 
                            $this->curl_options, $this->use_curl);
```

[As per the changes in PHP 7](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/migration70.incompatible.php#migration70.incompatible.other.new-by-ref). New objects cannot be assigned by reference.